# what may eat 300Gb of disc space on a clean CentOS?

Tags: docker

I have a clean CentOS server. Well, it's about a year old, but I'm working only in one directory there and I have a Docker daemon installed. The problem is that the amount of free disc space is going down, slowly and consistently. This is what I have now (after deleting `/var/lib/docker`):

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     377476072 313590548  63885524  84% /
devtmpfs         7597592         0   7597592   0% /dev
tmpfs            7486540         4   7486536   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            7486540     24932   7461608   1% /run
tmpfs            7486540         0   7486540   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1497312         0   1497312   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs            1497312         0   1497312   0% /run/user/1002
```

300Gb is occupied by something. I can't understand what that could be... When I'm trying to find the biggest files on disc, I'm getting some files with 40-80Mb size. Definitely not 300Gb. Any ideas?

This is my `du`:

```
$ sudo du -sh /*
0 /bin
270M  /boot
0 /dev
23M /etc
322M  /home
0 /lib
0 /lib64
0 /media
0 /mnt
0 /opt
0 /proc
48K /root
33M /run
0 /sbin
0 /srv
0 /sys
16M /tmp
1.4G  /usr
13G /var
```

These are my inodes:

```
# df -i
Filesystem        Inodes IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     213202208 81389 213120819    1% /
devtmpfs         1899398   318   1899080    1% /dev
tmpfs            1871635     2   1871633    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1871635   468   1871167    1% /run
tmpfs            1871635    13   1871622    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1871635     1   1871634    1% /run/user/1003
tmpfs            1871635     1   1871634    1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs            1871635     1   1871634    1% /run/user/1002
```

Comment: Files, most likely.

Comment: What's the size of `/dev/loop1`and `/dev/loop0` for you?
You can find that out via `sudo losetup /dev/loop0` giving you the file the loopback is attached to and then check that.

Comment: @HopelessN00b please, see the output of my `du` above...

Comment: Try `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /`.

Comment: Try: `find . -type f -size +10G` --> This will find any files larger no than 10GB

Comment: @GregL still nothing, showing just about 25Gb

Comment: @Jnrprimo I tried, there are no big files (

Comment: I'd say possibly corrupted file system, as `root` try `touch /forcefsck && reboot` and after do `sudo du -chs /*` and update your question.

Comment: @alexus I did what you suggested, no effect :(

Answer (score 3):

You might have deleted files since the `du` looks ok

`lsof | grep deleted`

That'll show you any processes holding open large files.. From there you can find the process like

`ps aux | grep pidNumberYouGetfromlsof`

That should give you an idea of what process to restart.

Comment: `lsof` returned nothing :(